# Accessing QT wdget properties

Tags: python, c++, qt, winapi

I have a question about programming around qt application.

I am creating a test for an application to make sure texts of some widgets are set properly based on data it connects to.  I started with win32 API to get main window handle and tried to navigate through its child windows.  After a  bit of struggle, I realized that the application is written in QT a lot more that I thought and I need a different approach.

From the test app, I was going to find a main window of the application, search through child windows using the retrieve hwnd, and get the text off the window or menu.  Is there any way to achieve this result using different approach?  BTW, I am doing this from Python and planning to use PyQT if I need to use QT library.  If I am really required to do so, I could use QT/c++ - the automation will become a bit complicated but I can do that.

Thanks,

Kay

Comment: add your code as well

Comment: there is not much code to add.   I made a call to FindWindow() and GetWindow( hwnd, GW_CHILD).  It returned 0 for HWND and used to check the child window state and properties using Inspect.exe.  It showed child windows are not accessible using conventional method.  I learned that QT windows are different than Win32 API windows.  Now, I am trying to find out how to tab into the text properties on widgets contained in the application windows.

Comment: Also, I tried GetMenu() with the hwnd from FindWindow(), but it returned 0 as well.

Comment: https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/technology-instrumentation/qt-testing.Hope it helps

Comment: Qobject class has a findChildren() API which given a widget name will find all its children widgets ...will that help you ? There is also an important class called Qmetaobject .. just go through the public APIs it has... 
Even iterating through the top level mainwindow and getting its children, you will have to dynamic_cast or qobject_cast to find the type of widget it is.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
How do I attach a running application to QObject class?  I looked up QObject::connect(), but it does not seem to be used for that purpose.

Comment: Qt applications do not use native windows for their widgets. That's why the Windows API call to `GetWindow` doesn't return any windows. If you want to navigate a Qt application's UI, you need to resort to [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). @NishantSharma: This would only be possible, if you run your test code inside the same process. The OP appears to be writing an external test application. There is no way to gain access to the internal in-memory representations of the widgets, so this does not apply.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions and all the help. I decided to create hooks in the product code for better testability and introduce testable product design concept, which is another battle that I need to fight. I can hack my ways through to do things, but nothing bits proper engineering approach.